# Script protected with SourceGuardian on Jelastic Cloud

Tags: installation, cloud, jelastic, protected-resource

can I install the script, protected using "SourceGuardian" into Jelastic Cloud? I tried to install "SourceGuardian Loaders", did not happen. Can not find any guide in this case. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily install into Jelastic your protected script. All you need is to follow the next steps:

1. Create environment from PHP templates with [Apache 2.4 on PHP 5.4](https://docs.jelastic.com/php-versions)
2. Open in browser Apache start page with *phpinfo()* function.
3. Copy address link of this page.
4. Open [SourceGuardian Loaders page](https://www.sourceguardian.com/loaders/download.php) and paste link in the following field.
5. Push "Detect" button.
   [image]
6. After that, you will receive the instruction How to install the SourceGuardian Loader.
   [image]
7. Download and extract the required loader *"ixed.5.4.lin"* by the placed link.
8. Open Config of the Apache node in the Jelastic dashboard and upload extracted *"ixed.5.4.lin"* file in *"/modules"* directory.
9. Open *"/etc/php.ini"* config file and add the following line `extension=ixed.5.4.lin` in Dynamic Extensions part. Save config file.
   [image]
10. Restart Apache node.

Profit, You can check the result at Apache start page (which include *phpinfo()* function) and at the [SourceGuardian page](https://www.sourceguardian.com/loaders/download.php).

Please, feel free to contact us if you need any further assistance.
Jelastic Support.